# Custom teams app with Azure authenticaton doesn't work in Teams desktop app while working in the browser

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

I am experiencing the same issue as this post.
Teams tabs work on the browser without an issue; however, it is showing an authentication error in the desktop teams application when opening our tab. The error is:

```
Error: in auth twana.daniel@email.com InteractionRequiredAuthError: Trace ID: b38d5d36-e582-41af-b354-b4f9ec607e00 Correlation ID: e09d4267-3af7-4f95-98f8-4c01a3f71e9d Timestamp: 2020-11-19 11:12:52Z
```

More strangely, though, the Teams tab does actually work on one of our Ubuntu computers, but not on a Mac or Windows teams app. So, what could be the reason for this?

We are using the MSAL library and getting the silent token, and in the desktop version, it shows an error when we are trying to get the silent token.

[See tab error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3f7f.png)

Comment: Are you using client credential flow?

Comment: Thanks for responding to this @Carl -> we are not taking client credentials in the teams tab.

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso)?

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha-MSFT the same code shared is using SSO while we are using the silent authentication. I would like to get it working without needing to use SSO. Is there anything that you can point me to for silent authentication to resolve this?

Comment: Currently there is no official sample for MSAL Silent authentication. Cold you please try using MSAL library?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT the issue seems to have resolved itself. I take it that the Microsoft teams team has patched this fix and resolve this.

Comment: This issue has now resolved itself, looks like Microsoft has pushed some fixes for this. @Nikitha-MSFT thanks for the support.